# Request “eth_sign” result promise never end

Tags: web3js

I have to sign a random string with my metamask. So created a js code like that:

```
await window.ethereum.request({
        method: "eth_sign",
        params: ["my address","My string"],
        id: "1"
    }).then(result => {
        console.log(result)
    }).catch(error => {
        alert(error.message);
    })
```

But i never got a response after i clicked "sign" on metamask window.
The promise is always in "pending" status.

[image]

Is it a bug or i'm doing somethings wrong ?

Thanks you !

EDIT: [image]

Comment: can you try -> params: [<hex-value>]

Comment: if this works then you need to hash ("myaddress" + "myString") and then give it in params instead of ("my address" "My string")

Comment: yes i made a mistake, there is a "," beetwen "myadress" and "string"

Comment: if i try what you said i got this error: MetaMask - RPC Error: e is undefined. It tells that there is no message to sign

Comment: Can you add what I said as a picture in your question

Comment: I added it to edit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it on the console of my browser
look like this

Connect to metamask and get accounts:

```
let accs;
ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' }).then(res => accs = res);
```

you should take an action in metamask at this point then:

```
let account = accs[0]
ethereum.request({ 
    method: 'eth_sign', 
    params: 
        [ account, '0xaaaa' ]
}).then(data => {
    console.log("data ", data);
})
```

The params are the address which will sign the message, and the message as hex start with 0x.

But you should not use **eth_sign** its bad, read here why and use the alternative
https://docs.metamask.io/guide/signing-data.html#signing-data-with-metamask

Comment: Thanks, "eth_sign" don't works although i do the same as you. But i tried with "personal_sign" and it's works well. Maybe "eth_sign" is deprecated now or it's because the website is not link to any ethereum RPC. Yeah i know for the securities issues but that's i use it in local and i never archieve to verify the signature of the "signTypedData_v4" method.

Comment: @Jean-benoitRichez Richez  Okay then modify my answer and then accept it if u can